# Read a file and sort the words

Tags: java, file, sorting

I am executing this part of code:

```
 Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<>();
        File file = new File("words.txt");
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
         while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
             String word = scanner.nextLine();
             int count = 1;
             if (wordMap.containsKey(word)) {                    
                 count = wordMap.get(word).intValue();
                 count++;
                 wordMap.remove(word);
                 wordMap.put(word, count);
             } else {
                 wordMap.put(word, count);
             }
           System.out.println(wordMap);
```

I just want to sort words in the file "words.txt". 
but the result I am getting is -

```
{{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1}
{{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1}
{{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1}
{{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1}
{\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1}
{=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1}
{=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 egg\=1}
{=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, dog\=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 egg\=1}
{=1, blue\=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, dog\=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 egg\=1}
{=1, moon\=1, blue\=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, dog\=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 egg\=1}
{=1, moon\=1, blue\=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, dog\=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1, fish\=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 egg\=1}
{=1, tooth\=1, moon\=1, blue\=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, dog\=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1, fish\=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 egg\=1}
{=1, love\=1, tooth\=1, moon\=1, blue\=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, dog\=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1, fish\=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 egg\=1}
{=1, love\=1, tooth\=1, moon\=1, blue\=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, dog\=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, end\=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1, fish\=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 egg\=1}
{the\=1, =1, blue\=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, love\=1, moon\=1, tooth\=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, dog\=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, end\=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1, fish\=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 egg\=1}
{the\=1, =1, blue\=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, love\=1, moon\=1, tooth\=1, please\=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, dog\=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, end\=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1, fish\=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 egg\=1}
{the\=1, =1, post\=1, blue\=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, love\=1, moon\=1, tooth\=1, please\=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, dog\=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, end\=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1, fish\=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 egg\=1}
{the\=1, =1, post\=1, blue\=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, love\=1, moon\=1, tooth\=1, please\=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, dog\=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, end\=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1, fish\=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 egg\=1}
{the\=1, =1, post\=1, blue\=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, love\=1, moon\=1, tooth\=1, please\=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, dog\=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, end\=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1, fish\=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 egg\=1}
{the\=1, =1, post\=1, blue\=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, love\=1, moon\=1, tooth\=1, please\=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, dog\=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, end\=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1, fish\=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 egg\=1}
{the\=1, =1, post\=1, blue\=1, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, love\=1, moon\=1, tooth\=1, please\=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0=1, dog\=1, }=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf110=1, end\=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww28600\viewh15800\viewkind0=1, fish\=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 egg\=1}
```

What is wrong in the code??? 
Thanks

Comment: can u tell how does your file looks like? and what do u mean by sorting the words? Are you just trying to calculate the frequency of all the words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You say you want words, but you're not reading words: you're reading lines:

   ```
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String word = scanner.nextLine();
   ```
2. Your file is not a simple text file, but an RTF file. It thus contains RTF formatting markup (font, bold, italic, etc.)
3. You never store anything other than 1 as value in the map: if the "word" is already in the map, you just increment count from 1 to 2, and do nothing with the count. You need to get the count from the map for that word, increment it, and put it back in the map.

Answer (score 1):

1. In order to sort the words in alphabetical order, it would be better to use a `TreeMap` rather than a `HashMap`. TreeMaps sort their keys in order - automatically.
2. The output you are seeing is the equivalent of calling `HashMap.toString()`. Instead try this:

   ```
   for (String key : wordMap.keys()) {
       System.out.println(key + ": " + wordMap.get(key));
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy, I am using TreeMap now. It made is simple.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, I created document using TextEditor, which creates .rtf doc. 
I converted it to .txt but it might have corrupted it.

I created different .txt file and it worked!!

```
 Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new TreeMap<>();
            File file = new File("wordCount.txt");
             Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
             while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                 String word = scanner.nextLine();
                 int count = 1;
                 if (wordMap.containsKey(word)) {                    
                    count = wordMap.get(word).intValue();
                     count++;
                     wordMap.remove(word);
                     wordMap.put(word, count);
                 } else {
                     wordMap.put(word, count);
                 }
             }
               System.out.println(wordMap);
             scanner.close();
```